# how to download private visibility spreadsheets using Google Sheets API authentication?

Tags: java, excel, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm still new to the API. I'm using the java drive api library, and trying to download a google spreadsheet. 
The public visibility spreadsheets are downloaded.
I have a credentials keys for google api.
Do I need to download private visibility spreadsheet documents use the Google Sheets API (java)?

Answer (score 0):

### Spreadsheet-api vs Drive-api

You need the google-drive-api to down load (with OAuth). 
And the Spreadsheet API to update, again with OAuth.

### Downloading Google Documents

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents